# Is there a way to get screen size in pixels in OpenGL-ES?

Tags: opengl-es, size, screen, pixel

How can I get screen size in pixels from OpenGL(ES) functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What platform are you developing on? I don't believe there is a way, based on the fact that for both Android and iOS devices, when I've followed books and tutorials, they use the OS's view/window size manager, rather than any intrinsic OpenGL ES function. It does seem to be an odd feature for a graphics api to lack, which is why I'm hesitant to claim this as the answer.

Also important, from [@ognian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2504283/ognian):

> You can call `glGetIntegerView` with `GL_VIEWPORT` before you ever call `glViewport`. It'll return `{0, 0, window_width, window_height)`. If you know your app is executed in full-screen, this will match the screen size. That's the closest you could ever get to querying screen resolution from OpenGL API

Comment: I'm asking about and within OpenGL-ES  standard API :)

Comment: Then the answer is: no, OpenGL ES doesn't provide API to get screen dimensions

Comment: It does seem to be an odd feature for a graphics api to lack, which is why I'm hesitant to claim this as the answer